# How can I make angular translate work with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-translate

I need to make my old angular 1.5.6 application localized. I use ui-router. And it doesn't work. I am trying to find the reason why, but it seems that others have questions about further steps, while I'm stuck on the first one...

Here is the simplified code of my app:

```js
angular
    .module('localeApp', [
      'ngCookies',
      'ui.router',
      'pascalprecht.translate'
    ])
    .config(
      ['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', '$translateProvider',
      function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
        $stateProvider
          .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'loginTpl.html'
          })
          .state('welcome', {
            url: '/welcome',
            templateUrl: 'welcomeTpl.html'
          })
          .state('other', {
            url: '/other',
            templateUrl: 'otherTpl.html'
          });

        $translateProvider.useMissingTranslationHandlerLog();// log missing translations
        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: 'locale-',// path to translations files
            suffix: '.json'// suffix, currently- extension of the translations
        });
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');// is applied on first load
        $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();// saves selected language to localStorage


    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$translate', function($rootScope, $translate) {
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
                $translate.refresh();
            });
    }]);
```

There are json files defined for each locale. For example the default `locale-en_US.json`:

```js
{
  "translate.welcome": "welcome",
  "translate.login": "login",
  "translate.other": "other"
}
```

And the template `loginTpl.html` page:

```
<p>This is {{translate.login | translate}} page</p>
```

Everything is in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tuobryFbuleOAWOvfWZT?p=preview).

I can see that the json file is retrieved, but it is not applied.
I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious, but I just can't figure out what it is...

Comment: Also use `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');` read more here https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security

Comment: Right, thank you @abhig10 for pointing this out. I've seen the warning message in the console and I wanted to address it at some point in the future, but with your snippet I can do it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap translate pattern with `'` a.e.:

Instead:

```
<p>This is {{translate.login | translate}} page</p>
```

write:

```
<p>This is {{'translate.login' | translate}} page</p>
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UjhuKy78b0IsBTSGHW6w?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Doh! I **knew** that this was some detail that I was missing. Thank you mate.